# Electric field lines of conductors through complex variables

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields

The Feynman Lectures on Physics Volume 2, Chapter 7, Section 7-2 discusses the shape of two dimensional electric field lines near conductors through the method of finding two dimensional solutions for the Laplacian equation

$$\nabla^2 \phi =0$$

with the help of complex variable functions. Given below is the link to the lecture for context.

https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_07.html

In the concluding parts of this section, Feynman gives three examples of complex functions which give the shapes of field lines for different types of conductors. I graphed these functions and I am having trouble in understanding the output.

For the sake of conciseness, I am just listing one:

$$F(z)=\frac{1}{z}$$

Here if $z=x+iy$ then we get, $F(z)=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}-i\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$. Thus we get $U(x,y)=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$ and $V(x,y)=\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}$. Setting $U(x,y)=A$ and $V(x,y)=B$ where $A,B$ are constants and then plotting these functions on Desmos for different values of $A,B$ gives us the following result.

[image: Plot in Desmos]

The red lines referring to $U(x,y)$ denote electric field lines and blue lines referring to $V(x,y)$ denote equipotential surfaces. Here are my questions:

1. How does Feynman come to the conclusion that these field lines correspond to the field lines of to line charges of opposite polarities very close to one another? Where are these line charges located?
2. For electrostatics, isn't $\nabla \times E=0$? However the electric field lines have a non zero curl over here.
3. How does one determine the conductor that produces field lines given by a particular function $F(z)$?

Comment: Welcome! Good question. I don’t have the opportunity to look into this further, but I’ll just point out that you’ve plotted the field of a 2D dipole (i.e. opposite polarity line charges coming out of the screen, infinitesimally close together). I encourage you to read about dipoles for a little intuition. Also, try calculating the curl (you may be surprised about its value!).

Comment: Well the answer to 1 is through experience, we already know what a dipole field looks like, and since this image is the same for every value of the third coordinate (also denoted as z), then it cannot be two point charges but a line of charges instead.